# Cannot deploy juju charms

Tags: juju, maas

I have a switch connecting all my nodes and NIC 1 from the maas server. NIC 2 is connected to the internet(external access). I enabled IP forwarding and NAT to allow our nodes to get external access. Am i missing something? or should i connect the switch directly to the internet.

Can you please tell me what you mean by MAAS's router?

THANK YOU!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you can access the internet from your MAAS server with the two NICs, and also enabled IP forwarding and NAT, you only need to make sure the MAAS cluster controller manages DNS and DHCP for its intranet NIC, and you set the "Router IP" to the same value as the NIC's IP. This will set all nodes' default gateway to that IP in they should be able to access the internet. You can use the MAAS web UI to edit the cluster controller settings.